# Error while inserting rows into db expecting string or bytes object

Tags: python, tuples, cx-oracle

I'm trying to insert a dataframe, derived from a csv, into an Oracle table and am getting the above message.

```
try:
    dfTuple = [tuple(x) for x in dfOrders.values]

    sqlTxt = 'INSERT INTO SCHEMA.MYTABLE\
                (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5)\
                VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5)'
    
    cursor.executemany(sqlTxt, [x for x in dfTuple])

    rowCount = cursor.rowcount
    print("number of inserted rows =", rowCount)

    connection.commit()

except Exception as err:
    print('Error while inserting rows into db')
    print(err) 
finally:
    if(connection):
       cursor.close()
       connection.close()
```

I've tried all types of variations of ( { [ with VALUES and none seem to work. In the DB Fields 1-5 are INT, INT, VARCHAR, DATE, VARCHAR... do I need to somehow convert the dataframe (comes through as all objects) into each correct datatype first?

This is what dfTuple looks like, with the original dfOrders.dtypes showing all as an object:

[image]

Comment: Don't make us guess what the full error actually is.  Please update the question and add the full error trace message.

Comment: That's the error. All it says is: Error while inserting rows into db expecting string or bytes object with no reference to a line or anything.

Comment: Oh, I see.  That's because you're catching the exception and just printing the bare message, which does not display the full traceback.  Please remove the `try/except` statements and just allow the exception to happen.

Comment: There's no need for the list comprehension `[x for x in dfTuple]`. Just use `dfTuple`.

Comment: The traceback goes to cursor.executemany (ty for the reminder to turn that part off). Unfortunately trying cursor.executemany(sqlTxt, dfTuple) yields the same result:  TypeError: expecting string or bytes object

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the contents of `dfTuple`?

Comment: I just edited the original post to show the contents.

Comment: Are you **sure** that is the full exact error message?  It doesn't say the actual type it found instead of string/bytes, and it doesn't say which specific column had the error?

Comment: Yes sir, that's it. If I could insert a screenshot I'd show you. It simply says TypeError: expecting string or bytes object and points to ---> 54 cursor.executemany(sqlTxt, dfTuple)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the date field needed to be converted first, and all NaN's replaced with 0, after creating the dataframe in order to have the df inserted into the table:

```
dfOrders['OrderDate']= pd.to_datetime(dfOrders['OrderDate'], format='%Y-%m-%d') 
dfOrders = dfOrders.drop_duplicates()
dfOrders.replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)
```